# How to use LibXML::Reader?

Tags: raku

raku freezes when trying to `use` LibXML::Reader.

```
use v6;

use LibXML::Reader;

sub dump-node($reader)
{
  printf "%d %d %s %d\n",
    $reader.depth,
    $reader.nodeType,
    $reader.name,
    $reader.isEmptyElement;
}

my LibXML::Reader $reader .= new(file => "filtered.xml")
  or die "cannot read filtered.xml";

while $reader.read
{
  dump-node($reader);
}
```

In Windows 11.

```
$ raku --version
Welcome to RakudoÔäó v2022.07.
Implementing the Raku┬« Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.07.
```

The funny string "RakudoÔäó" is what really shows in the terminal.

Changing the code page to UTF-8 fixed the funny characters.

```
$ chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

$ raku --version
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.07.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.07.
```

In fact I used the Perl module XML::LibXML, which has an excellent tutorial page, but I'd like to do it wih Raku.

Comment: Quick question: in the declaration/assignment line `my LibXML::Reader $reader`, what happens if you try just `=` instead of `.=` ?

Comment: @jubilatious1 it changes nothing ... I think it freezes in the compilation phase ...  if I put a `say` before `use`, nothing is printed ... if I put a `BEGIN say 0` before `use`, the 0 is printed ... if I also put `BEGIN say 1`  after `use`, the 1 is not printed

Comment: Okay, i think the problem is Rakudo balks at the "two-line" new-or-die statement. I can get it to fail gracefully if i just use `my LibXML::Reader $reader .= new(file => "filtered.xml") or die "cannot read filtered.xml";`, all on one line. I'll write it up as an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: FYI, if i supply an invalid file name and a "one-line" new-or-die statement, the script errors out with `Segmentation fault: 11` on the shell command line (I'm on a Mac).

Comment: well, now I don't know what to think ... I commented the `or die` part and and it started working ... and after that putting back the `or die` part it also works ... I think maybe some setup code of the module was failing before, and after it worked once, it works always now ... btw, with and invalid filename the script ends without a message error (even with the `or die` clause) ... if I create another script duplicating the original script, it also works (that's why I think the issue had something to do with the module, not the script)

thanks for the help, it's working now

Comment: you can write an answer and I'll accept it, because it solved my problem, even though the issue is a little cloudy for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not clear what's going on here, but I got the example code to work by placing the `or die` line all together with the line above it (I'm on a Mac):

```perl
use v6;

use LibXML::Reader;

sub dump-node($reader)
{
  printf "%d %d %s %d\n",
    $reader.depth,
    $reader.nodeType,
    $reader.name,
    $reader.isEmptyElement;
}

my LibXML::Reader $reader .= new(file => "filtered.xml") or die "cannot read filtered.xml";

while $reader.read
{
  dump-node($reader);
}
```

A few notes of interest:

1. For Perl fans, the traditional `something-or-die` is in the docs as valid  syntax; see: https://docs.raku.org/language/io
2. Feeding the script above an invalid file name results in `Segmentation fault: 11` at the command line. Interestingly, the `or die` error message `"cannot read filtered.xml"` never appears.
3. These results may have something to do with having to `--force-test` to install the LibXML module (standard install failed).
4. Changing the declaration line to more traditional syxtax below still fails to return the appropriate error:

```perl
my $reader = LibXML::Reader.new(file => "filtered.xml") or die "cannot read filtered.xml";
```

HTH.

https://libxml-raku.github.io/LibXML-raku/Reader